# identify x,y coordinate pair in a python x,y array

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

how can i identify the presence or absence of a pair of coordinates (x1,y1) in an array of many coordinates? eg in a sort of code:

```
myCoord = [1,2]

someCoords1 = [[2,3][4,5][1,2][6,7]]
someCoords2 = [[2,3][4,5][8,9][6,7]]

myCoord in someCoords1
True

myCoord in someCoords2
False
```

I have been experimenting with any() but can't get the syntax right or it's not the correct method. 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#or):

```
>>> myCoord = [1,2]
>>> someCoords1 = [[2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,7]]
>>> someCoords2 = [[2,3], [4,5], [8,9], [6,7]]
>>> myCoord in someCoords1 or myCoord in someCoords2
True
```

or using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> any(myCoord in x for x in (someCoords1, someCoords2))
True
```